# Random Forest classifier using caret, R

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest, r-caret, roc

I've been trying to run a random forest classifier over my data. But I've been facing a few problems, one of them is not knowing how to tune the parameters, and I've been getting this error:

```
Something is wrong; all the ROC metric values are missing:
      ROC           Sens          Spec    
 Min.   : NA   Min.   : NA   Min.   : NA  
 1st Qu.: NA   1st Qu.: NA   1st Qu.: NA  
 Median : NA   Median : NA   Median : NA  
 Mean   :NaN   Mean   :NaN   Mean   :NaN  
 3rd Qu.: NA   3rd Qu.: NA   3rd Qu.: NA  
 Max.   : NA   Max.   : NA   Max.   : NA  
 NA's   :15    NA's   :15    NA's   :15   
Error: Stopping
In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
```

Using random forest (with caret) has not been an easy task for me, on the contrary to other algorithms like gradient boosting, which is really easy.

I've split my data, I have my train and test sets ready. Now for the applying part:

```
ctrlCV = trainControl(method = 'repeatedcv', repeats = 3 , number = 10 , classProbs = TRUE , savePredictions = TRUE, summaryFunction = twoClassSummary )

tunegrid = expand.grid(.mtry=c(1:15))
RF_fit = train(CR~., data = train_set,
               method = "rf",
               metric="ROC",
               trControl = ctrlCV,
               ntree = c(2,3,5,7,10,12,20,25,50),
               nodesize = c(1:12),
               tuneGrid = tunegrid,
               verbose = F
               
)
```

I should note that I use the ROC metric all the time, and this error never happens, only with random forest.

I've tried gathering the hyperparameters, `nodesize` and `ntree`, into the `tunegrid` argument, but it didn't work either. I've searched A LOT for a solution but I found none.

###### My Question:

Can anyone here please help with this question? how do I use random forest in R? (it is crucial to keep the hyperparameters tunning).

If it helps, this is a subset of the train set, only the first 10 features out of 50, and the first 10 samples out of 1550 (notice the CR feature, which is the target feature, is it binary, so it shouldn't be that complicated to make the model):

```
structure(list(CR = c("nonComplete", "nonComplete", "nonComplete", 
"nonComplete", "nonComplete", "nonComplete", "nonComplete", "nonComplete", 
"nonComplete", "nonComplete"), gender = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 0), Adipocytes = c(0, 0.0506285834225855, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0569041924508975, 
0, 0, 0.00808021066294567), B.cells = c(0.00742221925097915, 
0.263202378087093, 0.0267219082648559, 0.0361954817583061, 0.0928176885154532, 
0.0506140213566825, 0.0987204055114184, 0, 0, 0.0236006578814983
), Basophils = c(0.0721681919709257, 0.0399824626647527, 0, 0.0907172739000218, 
0.0296141260275192, 0.0599342559816841, 0.648907959079008, 0, 
0, 0.127173359260902), CD4..memory.T.cells = c(0, 0.107843404965491, 
0, 0, 0.046793963565533, 0.0162061965993383, 0, 0, 0.0443566795774978, 
0), CD4..naive.T.cells = c(0, 0.0848006780049171, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0.0321380330205652, 0), CD4..T.cells = c(0, 0.0406217705464205, 
0, 0, 0.0279885857544357, 0.0143116136530688, 0, 0, 0.00740794560740805, 
0), CD4..Tcm = c(0.0266160520909386, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0105139321381762, 
0, 0.0175744489041248, 0.013011085302772), CD4..Tem = c(0.00740020174607587, 
0.103951222069191, 0.0197202686837326, 0, 0.143617036774303, 
0.0957411345212964, 0, 0.0480149975758639, 0.0305538134367263, 
0.0100153789723949)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x55ad18e03830>)
```

Comment: Hey, maybe all the CR levels are the same? nonComplete? then it's hard to run a classifier if the dependent variable has only one level

Comment: @MarcinKosiński no it's just the sample data I provided. The CR variable has two values, `Complete` and `nonComplete`. It's just that the first 60 samples are `nonComplete` and I provided only the first 10.

Comment: I would suggest running classifier on 10% of the data, then 20% of the data and then 30% and so on. Check out at which point it breaks and try to detect a row (or rows) that are causing the issue and then investigate rows by rows with human verification.